# Response HTTP 500 And SQL Injection

Tags: sql-injection

I have question about **500 HTTP ERROR**.
In my website for example:

**Response HTTP 200**

```
www.example.com/test.php?id=19
```

And when I add a semicolon (`;`) to the number I get an error:

**Response HTTP 500**

```
www.example.com/test.php?id=19;
```

Does that have any relation to an SQL injection?

Comment: It occasionally happens that web apps throw 500 when they encounter unexpected chars in the URL. You could check if `www.example.com/test.php?id=19&abc=123;` still yields the same error although the semicolon now belongs to an unrelated parameter.

Comment: yes still the same error

Comment: If that occurs with arbitrary parameters then it's probably not an SQL injection point.

Comment: Now when I use id=-19 that's give me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might - it is promising.  A well designed app would either silently remove the ; or would return a proper "bad input" error message.  That it blew up (500) is a good sign.

It doesn't necessarily mean that is vulnerable, however - they could be returning 500s in case of bad input, for instance.  But it certainly suggests you may want to try some more.  Try putting an '19 or sleep(2) = 1' (no quotes) - if it takes 2 seconds longer to respond, you are in like Flynn.

NOTE : this should be on either a site you have been asked to test, one you control or a demo site designed for cracking.  Doing this on some else's site could result in charges.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur response. The site what I have been asked it's website who give with bug bounty challenge

Comment: When I tried to add ' that change it's on %27

Comment: It's ASCII code of `'` that's normal.